# how to get checked checkbox row id in controller from partial view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, controller, partial-views

I am using partial view to show check boxes with every row.

```
<input type="checkbox" name="IsAdminConfirmed" id="@item.KidFeeId" value="@item.KidFeeId" style="display:block;margin-left:25%" />
```

I want to get the checked check boxes **row id** in controller. But i'm unable to get the values in controller. I'm using array of `int type` of check box name like below.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(int[] IsAdminConfirmed)
```

Can somebody help me with the solution .

Comment: Do you have a model in your view? If the Property name in your model it will come when its used in `ActionResult`. How do you post values to the `actionresult`. Ajax call or form Submit?

Comment: yes i am using model in the view.i tried both ajax and post method to get the values but it dint show any.

Comment: You code works fine. Are you sure the value of `KidFeeId` is typeof `int` and that the controls are within a form tag